# My array appears to have values but is giving a Subscript Out of Range error

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, recordset

I want to pass a row from a dao recordset to an array and then loop through the array, but it's not working. The below code produces a "subscript out of range" error.

```
Dim avarRow As Variant    
avarRow = rsSource.GetRows(1)
For i = LBound(avarRow) To UBound(avarRow)
   MsgBox avarRow(i)
Next
```

However, this code:

```
Dim avarRow As Variant    
avarRow = rsSource.GetRows(1)
For i = LBound(avarRow) To UBound(avarRow)
   MsgBox "There's something here..."
Next
```

Triggers the test message box the expected number of times - once for each field in the row I've captured. This must mean there's *something* in the array, so why can't I access it?

I've not used .GetRows before, so I suspect that's where my problem is. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: have you ever heard of `.Transponse` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194427%28v=office.15%29.aspx

*GetRows returns a two-dimensional array. The first subscript identifies the field and the second identifies the row number*

Try this

```
Dim avarRow As Variant
avarRow = rssource.GetRows(1)
For i = LBound(avarRow) To UBound(avarRow)
    MsgBox  avarRow(i, 0)
Next
```